# Datas not received with GameKit on swift

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

I'm currently making a multiplayer game with GameKit. I want to create a waiting viewController while each player receive the array of players and what they selected for their character.

Here is my extension

```
extension LoadingViewController: GKMatchDelegate {
    
    func sendData() {
            guard let match = match else { return }
            
            do {
                guard let data = gameModel.encode() else { return }
                try match.sendData(toAllPlayers: data, with: .reliable)
            } catch {
                print("Send data failed")
            }
        }
    
    func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceive data: Data, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {
        guard let model = GameModel.decode(data: data) else { return }
        gameModel = model
    }
}
```

My Override which waits until 2 players fill the gameModel

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.setupPlayers()
            if self.gameModel.players.count == 2 {
                if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                    // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
                    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") as? GameScene {
                        scene.match = self.match
                        scene.gameModel = self.gameModel
                        scene.localPlayer = self.localPlayer
                        scene.size = view.bounds.size
                        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
                        // Present the scene
                        view.presentScene(scene)
                        timer.invalidate()
                        
                        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                        
                        view.showsFPS = true
                        view.showsNodeCount = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the setupPlayers which is called each time to try adding a player and set his preferencies

```
private func setupPlayers() {

        guard let player2Name = match?.players.first?.displayName else { return }
        let player1 = Player(displayName: GKLocalPlayer.local.displayName)
        let player2 = Player(displayName: player2Name)
        
        var players = [player1,player2]
        
        players.sort { (player1, player2) -> Bool in
            player1.displayName < player2.displayName
        }
        if players.first?.displayName == GKLocalPlayer.local.displayName {
            if gameModel.players.count == 0 {
                players[0].index = .one
                players[0].race = .orc
                gameModel.players.append(players[0])
                localPlayer = players[0]
                sendData()
            }
        } else {
            if gameModel.players.count == 1 {
                players[1].index = .two
                players[1].race = .human
                gameModel.players.append(players[1])
                localPlayer = players[1]
                sendData()
            }
        }
    }
```

However the scene does not appear when i'm doing simulations, I tried finding the bug and when the first player go in setup Players it works and gameModel.players.count is now 1 but the second player never receive it and his own gameModel stay to one
Does anyone know why ?

Comment: 'Datas'?  In case you didn't know, the word 'data' is the plural form datum.

Comment: didn't know thx